# Terraform Cloud cannot Deploy Resources in Azure China Subscription

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

When trying to deploy using Terraform Cloud to Azure China I am getting the following error:
[image]

My code is very simple and has nothing to do with HSM:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  environment = "China"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "tfca_vm" {
  name     = "${var.name_prefix}tfca-vm"
  location = var.azure_location
}
```

I tried disabling the environment for the provider and ensuring all necessary resource providers were registered. Unfortunately, that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, downgrading to 3.62 worked with China Azue.

`

> Blockquote

```
azurerm = {
  source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
  version = "= 3.62.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a bug in AzureRM provider 3.63.